# Spring MVC,Jquery Autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, spring, model-view-controller, autocomplete, annotations

I am trying to implement Autocomplete feature using Spring MVC and Jquery.Employee list is coming from DB but from jquery; controller's function is not getting called.
Please see below code.

empDeatils.jsp

```
 `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ` `href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 `

 `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 `

 `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  `

 `<script type="text/javascript">
 `

$(document).ready(function() {


$(document).ready(function() {

$("#empName").autocomplete({

source: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getEmpList'

});

});

</script>



<form:input path="empName" cssClass="input-xlarge" id="empName" />
```

Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getEmpList", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")

public @ResponseBody List<String> getEmpNameList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {

List<String> empList = empDetailsService.getEmpNames(query);

return empList;

}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a RequestMapping annotation at your Controller CLASS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget the controller mapping in the url for the auto complete

I expect your controller Class looks like this

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/myController")
 public EmpController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getEmpList"  method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getEmpNameList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
        List<String> empList = empDetailsService.getEmpNames(query);
        return empList;
   }
 }
```

Then you have to use this url `myController/getEmpList` or `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/myController//getEmpList`

*If this does not fix the problem, then use a tool like firebug to see what the client send and what the server returns.*

Comment: tried to add RequestMapping on controller,but of no use.It is not at all hitting controller when i am typing any letter in text box; how can i see request and response.I took reference of this code from some example on net,that example is working but do not know why it is not.Please help. Thanks

Comment: A tool to view that requests would be firebug (a firefox plugin). It has the network tab, that shows the traffic (https://getfirebug.com/network)